# How does it happen that someone is pushing his/her codes into other's branch without branching out to that specific branch?

Tags: git, github

For example:

```
Person A is working in the X branch.
Person B is working in the Y branch.
Person C pulled the codes from Person B's branch by rebasing and git fetch.
Because it wasn't doing the fast-forwarding.
```

Now the problem is whenever Person A and Person B commit and push their codes into their branches and in GitHub, it shows that it pushed into that Person C's branch.

Can anyone please explain why it's happening?

Answer (score 1):

When you `git push` with no further arguments, you push to the local branch's *remote tracking branch*", sometimes also called the *upstream branch*. For example, `branchA` might track `origin/branchA`. But it does not have to be so. `branchA` could track `origin/branchC`.

You can see what all your local branches are tracking with `git branch -vv`.

```
branchA  24c27e21 [origin/branchA] Description of the last commit to branchA
```

The tracking branch is usually set up automatically, this can be controlled with [`branch.autoSetupMerge`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-branchautoSetupMerge). It can also be set manually when creating a branch with `git branch --track` and changed with `git branch --set-upstream-to`.

Note that this is all part of the local repository. PersonC should not affect how PersonA nor PersonB tracks.

---

The other way you can push to a differently named branch is to simply tell `git push` to do so.

```
git push origin branchA:branchC
```

This says to push `branchA` to `branchC` on the `origin` remote.

Comment: Thank you so much for explaining it. I wish I could vote for your answer but my reputation is not up to the mark.  :')

Comment: @monster957 Thank you, glad to help. Your rep will get there. For now, accept the answer once it lets you.